# I've never seen this type of flexible coupling, can someone tell me what it's called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, motors, mechanisms, coupling

Putting together a project, I've found this clutch but I've never seen this type before. It has a sort of flexible plate connecting the two parts, attached to both in two places corresponding to where the four teeth are. It seems to be working but I have no idea what torque it's ok for and how much I should compress it, if at all. Sorry for the shitty photo quality. [image: photo of the coupling]

Answer (score 2):

It could either be an *oldham coupling*.  The photo's a bit blurry. Here's a web page on oldham couplings. https://www.huco.com/products/couplings/oldham-couplings

[image: Oldham Coupling]

https://www.couplingtips.com/oldham-couplings/what-do-you-know-about-oldham-couplings/

or it could be a *Flexible flange coupling*

[image: Flexible flange coupling]

Comment: It's definitely not the Oldham, because it has a middel disk. But the second guess is correct.

Comment: See also Jaw or Spider couplings, like these: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1320&bih=856&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=MCs3XYL6M4Oxggf-j6KYCw&q=%28Jaw+OR+spider%29+coupling&oq=%28Jaw+OR+spider%29+coupling&gs_l=img.3...86790.93549..97294...0.0..0.67.547.9......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i8i7i30j0i8i30.QOqHiIdEE0g&ved=0ahUKEwiC0qj2sMvjAhWDmOAKHf6HCLMQ4dUDCAY&uact=5

Answer (score 0):

These drive clutches can be used to absorb drive train shocks and/or slight mis-alignments of the two shafts.

These are available in several sizes and capacities.

Flexible coupling or flexible drive coupling or flexible shaft couplings, see:

[enter link description here](https://www.skf.com/group/products/coupling-systems/flexible-shaft-couplings/index.html)